# Angular 8 Routing w/ Lazy Loading modules, child within a child route can skip parent route to access child

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have the following simple structure in my application that I am trying to work with:

```
/
/home
/admin
    /setup
    /other
```

I have the router using modules and lazy loading.  So the administrator page (`/admin`) of my application controls the access to the subpages for setting up the application.  Eventually, the Admin route (`/admin`) will be route guarded, but right now I am just building the empty templates and some simple tests for the routing.  This is all working.  Bad addresses are captured, missing addresses routing to `/`, etc.

My problem is in protecting my addressing so that people cannot bypass the true routes of the application and get to pages they should not see. Go to `/setup` instead of `/admin/setup`.

Trying to keep things self contained, I did not want to rely on route guards on all the submodules, just the routing under a page that is guarded.  This way, new modules loaded under the admin page will automatically be protected, in case a developer forgets to add the guard.  Also, the individual feature modules have their own routing, so this is not in one central location as most examples use.

The code works properly going to /admin/setup, /admin/set will go to the / root.  The problem I am having is that /setup also goes to the lazy loaded module for the Setup, which is a child of the Admin module routing.

EDIT: Update the routing modules based on suggestions, but the issue is still present.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./administrator/administrator.module').then(m => m.AdministratorModule) },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }     // Wrong route entered, return to main route
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ]
})
```

admin-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AdministratorComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'setup', loadChildren: () => import('./setup/setup.module').then(m => m.SetupModule) },
            { path: 'zzz', loadChildren: () => import('./zzz/zzz.module').then(m => m.zzzModule) }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

EDIT #2: Add example import of the Administrator routing in admin.module.ts.

admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AdministratorComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule,
        SetupModule,
        zzzModule,
        AdministratorRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class AdministratorModule { }
```

The problem is that I can go through properly to /admin/setup. However, you can also get to this page by simply going to /setup.  I do not want someone to be able to bypass the routing and get to restricted pages.

I am not sure how to protect against this route (`/setup`) working.

Comment: What is ‘./setup’ doing? Don’t know this syntax. Should not path:’admin’ in admin-routing be path:‘’? And path:’./setup’ be path:’setup’

Comment: From other documentation I have read, the ./setup is similar to a directory reference, where it means the current path, then the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I'm not sure I understand well your problem and I don't understand your admin routes too.

If I read your routes, I expect you have this routes:

- /
- /home
- /admin/admin (because you have admin in parent and admin in child)
- /admin/setup
- /admin/zzz

But I don't understand the './' before your routes. It can be the problem.

Did you try something like that ? (This is valid if you have a router-outlet into your AdministratorComponent too)

admin-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdministratorComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'setup', loadChildren: () => import('./setup/setup.module').then(m => m.SetupModule) }
            { path: 'zzz', loadChildren: () => import('./zzz/zzz.module').then(m => m.zzzModule) }
        ]
    }
];
```

admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AdministratorComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule
        AdministratorRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class AdministratorModule { }
```

If you import modules here, you will note use lazy-load and you will add routes in current module.

Comment: So I am using one <router-outlet> to simply move through pages.  The issue is with the lazy loading and each module having its own routing file.  If I do what you have suggested here in the admin-routing.module.ts, then I do not get the dashboard page, but the administrator page.  Adding the admin to your suggestion appears to bring up the pages correctly (dashboard and admin) but the /setup (localhost/setup) still works.

Comment: Also, the routing for /admin/setup does not work or load, but the /setup will load.

Comment: Where do you import your admin-routing.module ?

Comment: The last of the imports in the admin.module.ts imports the AdminRoutingModule, Added the information to the question.  Imports are CommonModule, MaterialModule (for the UI), SetupModule,zzzModule,AdminRoutingModule.

Comment: Why do you import (non lazy-load) a module that is routed as loadChildrens (lazy-load) ?
`SetupModule, zzzModule,` It will never works as expected.
Did you do the same for `AdministratorModule` into your `AppModule` ?

Remove all references of lazyloaded modules.

Comment: I have been updating the question with suggestions.  The problem is though, that I need it to work with Lazy Loading, not without, as this is a simple example, but these modules will be more complex in the real project.  The children part was not there originally, but added it due to suggestions.

Comment: Remove imports as in updated answer. It currently removes lazy-load and flat routes. So it's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AdministratorComponent },
    { path: 'setup', loadChildren: () => import('./setup/setup.module').then(m => m.SetupModule) }
    { path: 'zzz', loadChildren: () => import('./zzz/zzz.module').then(m => m.zzzModule) }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

which would not let user to navigate to only: `/setup`. Only `admin/setup` would exist. And no more `/admin/admin`

And within the lazy loaded modules setup.module and zzz.module. Make the same changes to any route there

Comment: This does not work.  As the app-routing.module.ts has some routes as well, if you simply go to the localhost, then the administration component displays, not the basic route.  The main page localhost/, should show my dashboard component. localhost/home will show another component.  With the change you suggest, it appears the adminstration component replaces the dashboard component.

Comment: The app-routing.module should stay the same. I the 'top' routing you should keep `{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./administrator/administrator.module').then(m => m.AdministratorModule) },` Only change in admin-routing.module